# how to create data table in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build the data table in flutter like below mentioned structure. but i don't know how i can do this .

| Fruit | anil fruit center | amol market | anand fruit mart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| Jackfruit | 100 | 0 | 30 |
| Watermelon | 20 | 400 | 300 |
| Dragonfruit | 700 | 50 | 600 |

Here i have purchased different fruits from different vendors . here is i have purchased one fruit from more than one vendor or from one vendor. Vendor and fruit  list can be change. data come in JSON format. so now how i can arrange data according to fruit and vendor wise in data table. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, [horizontal_data_table](https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:horizontal_data_table/horizontal_data_table.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  HDTRefreshController _hdtRefreshController = HDTRefreshController();

  static const int sortName = 0;
  static const int sortStatus = 1;
  bool isAscending = true;
  int sortType = sortName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    user.initData(100);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _getBodyWidget(),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBodyWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: HorizontalDataTable(
        leftHandSideColumnWidth: 100,
        rightHandSideColumnWidth: 600,
        isFixedHeader: true,
        headerWidgets: _getTitleWidget(),
        leftSideItemBuilder: _generateFirstColumnRow,
        rightSideItemBuilder: _generateRightHandSideColumnRow,
        itemCount: user.userInfo.length,
        rowSeparatorWidget: const Divider(
          color: Colors.black54,
          height: 1.0,
          thickness: 0.0,
        ),
        leftHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        rightHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        enablePullToRefresh: true,
        refreshIndicator: const WaterDropHeader(),
        refreshIndicatorHeight: 60,
        onRefresh: () async {
          //Do sth
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
          _hdtRefreshController.refreshCompleted();
        },
        htdRefreshController: _hdtRefreshController,
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getTitleWidget() {
    return [
      FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: _getTitleItemWidget(
            'Name' + (sortType == sortName ? (isAscending ? '↓' : '↑') : ''),
            100),
        onPressed: () {
          sortType = sortName;
          isAscending = !isAscending;
          user.sortName(isAscending);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: _getTitleItemWidget(
            'Status' +
                (sortType == sortStatus ? (isAscending ? '↓' : '↑') : ''),
            100),
        onPressed: () {
          sortType = sortStatus;
          isAscending = !isAscending;
          user.sortStatus(isAscending);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Phone', 200),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Register', 100),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Termination', 200),
    ];
  }

  Widget _getTitleItemWidget(String label, double width) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      width: width,
      height: 56,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    );
  }

  Widget _generateFirstColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(user.userInfo[index].name),
      width: 100,
      height: 52,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    );
  }

  Widget _generateRightHandSideColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                  user.userInfo[index].status
                      ? Icons.notifications_off
                      : Icons.notifications_active,
                  color:
                      user.userInfo[index].status ? Colors.red : Colors.green),
              Text(user.userInfo[index].status ? 'Disabled' : 'Active')
            ],
          ),
          width: 100,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].phone),
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].registerDate),
          width: 100,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].terminationDate),
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

User user = User();

class User {
  List<UserInfo> userInfo = [];

  void initData(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      userInfo.add(UserInfo(
          "User_$i", i % 3 == 0, '+001 9999 9999', '2019-01-01', 'N/A'));
    }
  }

  ///
  /// Single sort, sort Name's id
  void sortName(bool isAscending) {
    userInfo.sort((a, b) {
      int aId = int.tryParse(a.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
      int bId = int.tryParse(b.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
      return (aId - bId) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }

  ///
  /// sort with Status and Name as the 2nd Sort
  void sortStatus(bool isAscending) {
    userInfo.sort((a, b) {
      if (a.status == b.status) {
        int aId = int.tryParse(a.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
        int bId = int.tryParse(b.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
        return (aId - bId);
      } else if (a.status) {
        return isAscending ? 1 : -1;
      } else {
        return isAscending ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });
  }
}

class UserInfo {
  String name;
  bool status;
  String phone;
  String registerDate;
  String terminationDate;

  UserInfo(this.name, this.status, this.phone, this.registerDate,
      this.terminationDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank for replay jim but in your horizontal data table your column head and number of  columns are fixed but in my case column heads and number of column are depending on the data which is come from database.vendors are not fixed that vendors columns can increase if i purchase some fruits  more than 5 different vendors. than columns and head of column will change according to vendors entry in database.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create the table structure you want, flutter has a great widget to arrange data in the table its called [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

DataTable has many features you need.

Check out this video on how to use DataTable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktTajqbhIcY

*I think DataTable is enough you don't need any package.*